# Push Notification isn't delivered

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, parse-platform

my app uses Push Notification between clients as it uses a chat service [Note: i'm using PFPush from Parse.com]. When i'm sending a push that has it's Data property set to a value, the push is received when the app is in the foreground but not when it's in the background. i'm not sure if the app is receiving it but not displaying a notification alert or not. However, sending a push without setting a data it's working fine. I read that setting a data will overwrite the message property. so how could i fix that as the data property is something crucial in the delivery process as it holds data of the chat text and i cannot omit it? should i be sending two notifications? one to alert second for data? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Oh your welcome. That is all i know let me search if i find any other solution. It should be one that you see a lot of apps that do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending them both.i guess you should fix it in Notification settings.

Comment: the notification settings are well configured. when i send a notification from the PN console it works fine. the problem seems to be in setting an NSDictionary to the Data property. i read that if i set the Message and Data properties they will override each other. So as i said, sending a PN without Data works fine. Thank you for your input.

Comment: okay it's working when i send two PN. one with the data and the other with a message in case the app is in the background.